# React Component props won't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

`this.props.images` is not properly updating when I dispatch the array of images. The array just displays as empty, though the resulting array is not.

[image: screenshot of arrays]

I've linked my repo for the project and listed the files that need to be referenced.

[React Web App Repo](https://gitlab.com/julianahill/simple-react-pwa)

[Furbabies Co Web App](https://www.furbabiesco.com/)

The files that you need to look at are as follows:

- components/Content/Profile/Images.js
- components/Content/User.js
- store/image.js
- store/images.js

If you want to help with this project by contributing that'd be great! :)

Comment: You'd get much better responses if you could post specific pieces of your code that you suspect are not working. Having a repo is great, but what you're asking here is consultancy work.

Comment: it was a typo -_- lol

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your app, but it didn't work. So the code below is assuming that everything else is set up and working properly in your app.

Instead of using the class decorator `@`, try connecting directly to the class (also, I'd highly recommend cleaning up your code, it's really hard to read).

Several notes:

1. Use better declarative names for all of your functions (`this.update()` -- update WHAT!?!? While it makes sense to you, to a developer who has never seen your app, they'll ask the same question)
2. Follow the recommended way to setup a [redux reducer
   switch/case](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions).
3. Combine similar redux state into one reducer. For example, you have `image` and `images`. What's the difference? If one is a number for indexing and the other is an array for images, that's okay, you can still use a single reducer (as shown below).
4. Create an `actions` folder to handle Redux actions and a `types` folder for Redux types
5. Use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for async functions (like `fetch`)
6. Create a separate `Upload Images` form. Don't lump it with your `Images` component.
7. You actually don't need Redux here (unless you're sharing it with other nested components). You can just use React's local `state`.

**types/index.js** (redux action types)

```
export const UPDATE_IMAGE_INDEX = "UPDATE_IMAGE_INDEX";
export const UPDATE_IMAGES = "UPDATE_IMAGES";
```

**reducers/imagesReducer.js** (structure your `switch/case`s like so)

```
const initialState = {
   index: 0,
   data: []
}

const imagesReducer = (state=initialState, { type, payload }) => { //es6 destructing -- type=action.type, payload=action.payload
  switch (type) {
    case 'UPDATE_IMAGE_INDEX':
      return { ...state, index: payload } // accessible via state.images.index
    case 'UDPATE_IMAGES':
      return {...state, data: payload } // accessible via state.images.data
    default:
      return state
  }
};

export default imagesReducer;
```

**actions/imageActions** (redux action creators)

```
import * as types from '../types';

// the following is a Redux thunk action (thunk handles returned async functions -- you have to install it and add it as middleware)
export const fetchImages = (id, type) => dispatch => (
  fetch(`/images/${type}/${id}`) // fetch images
    .then(res => res.json()) // turn result into JSON
    .then(({ result }) => dispatch({ type: types.UPDATE_IMAGES, payload: result })) // send result to `imagesReducer`
    .catch(() => console.log('Network error...'));
)

// this updates the image index
export const updateImageIndex = payload => dispatch => (
  dispatch({ type: types.UPDATE_IMAGE_INDEX, payload })
)

// this should upload an image, save it, then return all current images
export const uploadImage = (type, id, data) => dispatch => (
   fetch(`/images/${type}/${id}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
     }
   )
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(({ result }) => dispatch({ type: types.UPDATE_IMAGES, payload: result }))
   .catch(() => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_ERROR', payload: { message: 'Network error...try again later!'} }));
)
```

**components/Content/Profile/ShowImages.js** (displays images -- nothing else; also, allows you to view them one by one via buttons)

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchImages, updateImageIndex } from '../../../actions/imageActions';

class ShowImages extends PureComponent {   
  componentDidMount = () => {
    inputs.lazyload(`/css/images.min.css`).catch(() => console.log('Network error...'));
    this.props.fetchImages(this.props.type, this.props.id); // fetches images via redux action creator shown above
  }

  handlePrevClick = e => {
    const { index, images } = this.props;
    if (index-1 <== images.length) {
       this.props.updateImageIndex(index-1); // reduces redux image index by 1 via redux action creator shown above
    }
  }

  handleNextClick = () => {
    const { index, images } = this.props;   
    if (index+1 <== images.length) {
       this.props.updateImageIndex(index+1); // increases redux image index by 1 via redux action creator shown above
    }
  }

  // ideally this should be done BEFORE being sent to the front-end, as is, every time this.props.index is updated, this has resort them -- ruins client-side performance and wastes resources.
  sortImages = () => {
   return this.props.images.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.isDefault && b.isDefault) return a.src.localeCompare(b.src);
      return a.isDefault || b.isDefault;
    });
  }


  render = () => {
    const { index, images } = this.props;
    const sortedImages = this.sortImages();
    const prev = images.length && index > 0 ? '<' : '+';
    const next = images.length && index < images.length ? '>' : '+';

    return (
      <div className='images'>
        <button className='prev' onClick={this.handlePrevClick}>
          {prev}
        </button>
        <img src={sortedImages[index]} />
        <button className='next' onClick={this.handleNextClick}>
          {next}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   images: state.images.data,
   index: state.images.index,
   user: state.user,
   type: store.current.type
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ fetchImages, updateImageIndex }); 


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowImages)
```

Comment: yeah, it shouldn't work...you need aws creds to run it :/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use the componentWillReceiveProps in the Component life cycle

see react docs [--> here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

or just use pureComponents (functions nether classes)

pureComponents updates on props by default